# Spring data Elasticsearch @Field boolean creating two fields in mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I am facing one issue with the boolean field in elastic search entity.
In the entity which i have there is a boolean field present which is

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
private boolean isClosed;
```

When i see the mapping it creates two mappings as shown below.

```
 "isClosed": {
    "type": "boolean"
},
"closed": {
    "type": "boolean"
}
```

I am trying to find out why is it creating such mapping any suggestion would be  helpful.

Comment: How're you creating the index? Are you creating any mappings on the go?

Comment: No when i start the server spring data elastic search is creating this mapping during index creation for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is most likely a convention violation.

Convention:

```
private boolean closed;

public boolean isClosed() {
   return closed; 
}
```

So it takes isClosed as a variable but also closed because you most likely have the isClosed() getter which should result in closed as the variable in elastic.

Do you have `@Mapping(mappingPath ="xxx")` at your documents top level? This would overwrite any @Field anyway and index based on convetional names.